# Hiding iCloud folders from search on iOS

Tags: ios, spotlight, file-sharing

I have a few files that come up frequently in my searches from the iOS equivalent of spotlight (idk what this is called just swiping down on the home screen) that I dont want previewed in search. I am trying to figure out how to hide them from search or prevent their previews (images) from showing up.

I have tried setting the containing folder to .noindex but that didn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot isolate one folder to be hidden from iOS spotlight, as per my knowledge.

To fully remove Files app from showing files in spotlight, Settings → Siri and Search → Files, turn it off.